# Ignore/skip specific field in Hibernate schema validation

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, database-schema

I'm using Java and Quarkus 2.16.x. I have a DB entity having a field that is existing only in some databases and not in others.
In my `application.properties` I'm using `quarkus.hibernate-orm."iad".database.generation=validate` and I need to keep it to validate the general schema.

What I need is just to ignore the specific field inside my entity during the schema validation, so that the application starts regardless of the presence of the field in the DB schema I choose!

Is there anything like an `@Ignore` annotation from Quarkus or Java or Hibernate that I can use for that field?

I tried to use `@Transient`, but when the column is existing in the DB the value of the field is always ignored while doing set/get operations!

Thanks

Comment: Is it really just validation though where you want this skipped?  I'd imagine no - that you really want Hibernate to simply treat the attribute as transient on one db and persistent (non-transient) on the other.  And that's not possible.  Even if the validation passed, you will still have trouble at runtime - as you've seen with `@Transient` and not persisting on one hand; but the other is true as well - without `@Transient` in the case of the schema NOT having that column, you will run into SQL errors at runtime